# Javascript - change input value on click not working

Tags: javascript

Here's a div which represents cart item qty field:

```
<div class="cart_quantity_div">
  <form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <button class="cart_qty_controls" onclick="minusOne(qty_field_<?php echo $item_id; ?>)">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="cart_item_qty" value="<?php echo $each_item['quantity']; ?>" size="1" maxlength="3" id="qty_field_<?php echo $item_id; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="qty_adjust_cart<?php echo $item_id; ?>" value="change" class="cart_qty_adjust_btn"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_item_to_adjust_qty" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

It is a draft version so don't pay attention to submit and hidden inputs

And JS code:

```
function minusOne (input_id){

var subtracted_qty = document.getElementById(qty_field_id).value = document.getElementById(qty_field_id).value - 1;
document.getElementById(qty_field_id).value = subtracted_qty;
}
```

I want to change value of input text field by clicking minus button by -1. But for some reason it's not working.

Can you, please, review my code and find whats wrong with it. Or maybe there is some better ways to do such qty change..

Comment: Lets simplify my question a bit:
I have <button onclick="minusOne(somevalue)">-</button>
and <input id="somevalue">
How can I pass this "somevalue"  to JS function?
"somevalue" is dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not set the variable `qty_field_id`, nor does it use the variable `input_id`. If `input_id` is referring to the same value as PHP’s `$item_id`, then try adding the following line to the top of the JavaScript function:

```
var qty_field_id = "qty_field_" + input_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use inline javascript and you aren't referencing the correct element. Try this instead:

HTML:

```
<div class="cart_quantity_div">
  <form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <button class="cart_qty_controls" data-productId="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="cart_item_qty" value="<?php echo $each_item['quantity']; ?>" size="1" maxlength="3" id="qty_field_<?php echo $item_id; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="qty_adjust_cart<?php echo $item_id; ?>" value="change" class="cart_qty_adjust_btn"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_item_to_adjust_qty" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('cart_qty_controls')).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-productId');
        document.getElementById('qty_field_' + id).value -= 1; 
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you explain the `[].slice.call` code? It seems a bit strange to me

Comment: @CharlieHarding it creates an iterable array out of the `html collection` returned by `getElementsByClassName()`, so that you can run Array.prototype functions on it (like forEach() or map() e.g.). It's quite the same as  `[].forEach.call()`, but faster

Comment: Why is it not possible to just run the following?

`document.getElementsByClassName('cart_qty_controls').forEach(function(el){• • •})`

on the

Comment: Because forEach is an Array.prototype, not a htmlCollection prototype. And document.getElementsByClassName() doesn't return an array but a htmlCollection